# Want to show specific channels in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

```
[#list activeChannels?sort_by("number") as channel]
<div class="kanal">
<div class="row">

    <div class="column20" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" style="vertical-align: middle;" id="${channel.id}" ${channelSubscriptions?seq_contains(channel.id)?string("checked='checked'", "")}/>
            <label for="${channel.id}"></label></div>
    </div>

<div class="column80"><div style="width:30%; float:left;">
[#if channel.imageUrl?has_content]
<img src=" ${channel.imageUrl} " style="width: 85%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"> <!-- Bildgröße-->
[#else]&nbsp;[/#if]</div>
<div class="title" style="width:70%; float:left;">${channel.name}[#if channel.description?has_content]<br /><span style="font-style:italic; font-weight:normal;">${channel.description}</span>[/#if]</div>

    </div>

</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

</div>
[#if channel_has_next]
<div style="height: 20px; width: 100%;"></div> <!--Abstand zwischen Kanälen-->
[/#if]
[/#list]
```

What is does: 
it list all active Channels in a row from number 1 to 10

What i want it to do:
i want list all active Channels from number 1-4 and 6-10

Does somebody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop with index as below while ignoring specific index as 5:

```
 <#list 0..10 as i>
   <#if x != 5>
       ${activeChannels[i]}
   </#if>
 </#list>
```

In your case if channel is a number just add after list

```
 [#list activeChannels?sort_by("number") as channel]
 [#if channel.number != 5]
```

And close if before  [/#list] as:

```
 [/#if] [/#list]
```

Comment: thx, but my programmings skills are not good enought for this.

Comment: I added a specific answer

Comment: Should be: `[#if channel.number != 5]`. Note the `.number`.

Comment: Is it possible to add more channel i do not want to see. like `[#if channel.number != 5 and != 4]` ?

Comment: Yes, like this: `<#if channel.number != 5  && channel.number != 4 >`